# I added a PPA, yet Ubuntu can't find the icon theme package I'm looking for

Tags: icons, themes, ppa, 17.04

I've been looking for icon themes to install in Ubuntu 17.04. I added the PPA with `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:upubuntu-com/icons`, however when I try to install an icon theme I want with `sudo apt-get install matrilineare-icon-theme` it simply says it wasn't found even though I added this PPA three times.

```
E: Unable to locate package matrilineare-icon-theme
```

I am running Ubuntu 17.04, freshly installed which has GNOME desktop environment. I have also checked the package list online for this PPA on Launchpad and all the packages that I'm trying to install are there.

Comment: Did you 'sudo apt update'? Give me an output.

Comment: @Peter - Yes, many, many times. I don't think there was a "404 Not Found error, except for some old 2011 ppa's i was planning to remove:

Comment: My guess it the ppa does not support 17.04

Comment: Hmm, I think the whole output is too long, but does this have to do with anything?: "W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/icons/ubuntu zesty Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
"

Comment: That was my conclusion as well, though I find it inefficient to install a whole other distro just to use an icon pack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ppa:upubuntu-com/icons is out-of-date. The only currently supported Ubuntu release in that PPA is Ubuntu 14.04. You can find other icon themes at [gnome-look.org Icon Themes](https://www.gnome-look.org/browse/cat/132/ord/latest/).

Comment: Ahh, alright. Though I have seen quite a few new icon packs in there, I guess this is the case. Guess I won't be able to find a good icon pack, after all!